# Rule-based symbology: setting color/size of icon

Tags: qgis, symbology

QGIS 3.22 LTR - how can I set the color and size of the icon/symbol of th members in a vector set by a rule? I am wondering how to access the color/size attribute of the current data member. I can't figure it out...

Comment: Have you tried double-clicking the symbol in front of the specific rule you want to set the symbology for?

Comment: Yes - maybe i did not describe my problem in detail - i am wondering how to set the color and/or icon of the current item with the expression builder.

E.g. in the moment: ""ERP-MAX vertikal" < q1("ERP-MAX vertikal") OR "ERP-MAX horizontal" < q1("ERP-MAX horizontal")" for a specific symbology (icon size and color). I Would be nice to compute the icon size and color from attributes for every item.

Comment: Have you had a look at `data defined override`?

Comment: Thanks, Eric - this is the solution - great!